# Hide parent element but child stays using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code:

```
<a onclick="placesclick();" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <span class="place">3</span>
</a>
```

I need to make the span unclickable, so I was thinking about hiding the "a" element but leave the span shown. Is it possible somehow easily without removing the whole "a" and then adding span again? Or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can format source code with the 0101010 button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: thank you, sorry for troubles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Working demo`](http://www.jsfiddle.net/dactivo/3xx2u/)

If I understand you need to have the structure: `<a><span></span></a>`, but the clickable event of these tags must be deleted.

You have to add:

```
$("#aunclickable").click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Alright so I can add this function to my site and then on particular command Ill add the "aunclickable" class to my "a" and it will be unclickable? Will it not interfere with the onclick action?

Comment: As I can see thanks to your demo, it wont. Thank you, that looks great.

Comment: @aGr - It will replace the onclick action so that it does not execute.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to style anchor not to look like link. Remove onclick event of anchor tag if its not require in that case.

```
.noLinkSpan{
   color:black;  // set to your normal text color
   cursor:default;
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer not to remove the onclick action, though I might need sometime after

Comment: No issues you can check in that function, e.g. $(this).hasClass("noLinkSpan"){ //do nothing } else { //continue function }